# Open file in Wordpad, print it and then close it

Tags: powershell

I am trying to open a TXT file in WordPad, print it and then close it. Here is the code I am trying with no luck.

```
Start-Process Wordpad.exe C:\temp\MyTextFile.txt -Verb Print -Wait
```

I can get this to work fine when using Notepad, but my users want to use Wordpad, I get this error with Wordpad:

> Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: No application is associated with the specified file for this operation.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this will do what I need

```
Write.exe /p C:\temp\MyTextFile.txt
```

I need to learn to search for answers better :-)

Comment: If all you're after is printing text, consider `Get-Content C:\temp\MyTextFile.txt | Out-Printer`